# Why does `cd %appdata%` not work on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

One way to get into it is by using the Run dialog box using <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. And then type `%appdata%` into it and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

But not being able to `cd` into it is causing issues when trying to get to that folder from the terminal. Is it possible to make it work somehow?

Comment: If you paste %AppData% into a File Explorer window does it navigate to your users AppData directory, instead of submitting a comment, edit your question

Comment: Which shell are you using? Have you checked the syntax for referencing environment variables in the documentation of the shell you are using? For example, in POSIX sh, the syntax for referencing an environment variable would be `$AppData`, not `%AppData%`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is it possible to make it work somehow?

You may be on a different drive.

**`cmd` shell:**

Try `cd /D %appdata%`

Example:

```
C:\>f:

F:\test>cd /D %appdata%

C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming>
```

**`Powershell`:**

```
cd "$env:appdata"
```

Or

```
Set-Location "$env:appdata"
```

Note: `cd` is an alias for `Set-Location`

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [CD Change Directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [Windows Environment variables - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-env.html)
- [Set-Location - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/set-location.html)